# How to resolved the Status Code 500 error (The Print Job Process was cancelled.)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I used the WebClientPrint 2.0 for automatically print the pdf file from Client side's printer.
For that i add Neodynamic.SDK.WebClientPrint.dll file in my project and also installed the WebClientPrintAspNet20.exe in my system. 
I tried this code http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-PDF-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-default-printer-without-print-dialog/

But it will not work, and give me the error:
(Status Code : 500) The Print Job Process was cancelled.

Please Give me suggestions to solve this error.
Or
Any other code to Print Pdf directly from Client Side's Printer.

Comment: Hi. I am having the same error. Did you find a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We are using this as well in an ASP.NET application and I recently got the same error.  What happened in our case was the WCP client cannot connect to the server handler and it throws a 500.  If you are using a handler (.ashx), as Neodynamic recommended to  us, I would check the web.config and make sure there is a location section defined correctly for the handler, i.e. the ashx file and you omit or comment out the system.webServer section within the location section, as below:

```
  <location path="Pages/NeodynamicWebClientPrint.ashx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <!--system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer-->
  </location>
```

For the purposes of troubleshooting, try to navigate to the direct link to the handler, example:

https://www.ourdomain.com/OurApp/Pages/NeodynamicWebClientPrint.ashx

Before the location setting edit, I got a 500 error, afterward I was able to navigate and the web client print application started working for us.